# C# Xamarin Geolocator Plugin not updating location

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app using Xamarin Forms which tracks a user's location. I am currently trying to use the [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/geolocation-for-ios-android-and-windows-made-easy/) `Geolocator` plugin for tracking a user's location. I have followed the steps in the plugin's tutorial, but my location is currently not refreshing.

Here is my code:

```
public WhosOnFarm ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

    locator.PositionChanged += (sender, e) => {
        DisplayAlert("Success", "Your position has changed!", "OK");
        var position = e.Position;
        longitudeLabel.Text = "Longitude: "+position.Longitude.ToString() + " Latitude: " + position.Latitude.ToString();
    };
}
```

In the tutorial it did not specify the type of `locator` so I assumed the data it requires it `CrossGeolocator.Current;`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to answer your question without the project set-up. Location plug-ins, such as the GeoLocation, require some properties (rights) to be set-up in the project. Did you add those? On which platform are you using it? On what device or emulator did you test it?

Comment: Sorry if my question is vague. I have added the appropriate permissions such as "ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION" and "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" I am testing it on a Galaxy S7 Edge as well as android_23_x86 emulator

Answer (score 0):

> I have implemented same library following is the my code which
>   perfectly working on android and iOS

```
     public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CrossGeolocator.Current.AllowsBackgroundUpdates = true;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += Current_PositionChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            updateLocation();
        }

        private async void updateLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
                locator.AllowsBackgroundUpdates = true;
                var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

                if (position == null)
                {
                    lblData.Text = "null gps :(";
                    return;
                }
                lblData.Text = string.Format("\nTime: {0} \nLat: {1} \nLong: {2} \n Altitude: {3} \nAltitude Accuracy: {4} \nAccuracy: {5} \n Heading: {6} \n Speed: {7}",
            position.Timestamp, position.Latitude, position.Longitude,
            position.Altitude, position.AltitudeAccuracy, position.Accuracy, position.Heading, position.Speed);

                mapVar.MoveToRegion(
   MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
       new Position(position.Latitude,position.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(1)));
                await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(1, 2, true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }


        private void Current_PositionChanged(object sender, Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.PositionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Position != null)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    var position = e.Position;
                    lblData.Text = string.Format("\n\nTime: {0} \nLat: {1} \nLong: {2} \n Altitude: {3} \nAltitude Accuracy: {4} \nAccuracy: {5} \n Heading: {6} \n Speed: {7}",
            position.Timestamp, position.Latitude, position.Longitude,
            position.Altitude, position.AltitudeAccuracy, position.Accuracy, position.Heading, position.Speed);
                    mapVar.Pins.Clear();
                    mapVar.Pins.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Pin
                    {
                        Position = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude),
                        Type = Xamarin.Forms.Maps.PinType.Place,
                        Label = "My Location"
                    });

                    mapVar.MoveToRegion(
   MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
       new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(1)));

                });
            }
        }
    }
```